# List and remove Telegram groups for a bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

It seems that if your Telegram bot allows groups, anyone can add the bot to any group, not just the bot's creator.

How can you view what groups your bot is connected to?
and How can you remove your bot from a group?

My bot has been added to several supergroups that spam 100k messages to it per day. I would like to remove it from these groups, but still allow the bot to be in other groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get list of chats that bot joined at this time.

There have a [leaveChat](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?leaveChat-565f9f8d) method, you can call it when receive messages from your "blacklist", or any unknown group.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent users from adding the bot to groups? (but it still be allowed in some groups)

Comment: You can only use `/setjoingroups` to disallow ALL user add your bot to group, including his father :(

Comment: Does this remove the bot from all its current groups? or only disallow having it join new groups?

Comment: This command won't make your bot leave groups, you have to use `leaveChat` for each group